# this.emit("ready") does nothing in node.js

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I'm trying to write a simple library in node.js. Here's my library code, in a file called "index.js" in the "lib" folder:

```
var util = require("util");
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
util.inherits(Foo, EventEmitter);

function Foo() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

Foo.prototype.Something = function() {
  console.log("Hello World")
  this.emit("ready")
}

module.exports = Foo
```

And here's some test code in a file called index.js in the root of my project folder:

```
var Foo = require("./lib/index.js");
var foo = new Foo();

foo.Something();

foo.on("ready", function() {
    console.log("Blah")
})
```

When I run this code with node `v0.12.7`, I see "Hello World", but not "Blah"

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, as I've used emitters before in another project, but even copying that code doesn't work.

Any clues as to why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you are doing wrong is that you call the function (emit the event) before you listen to it.

Just invert the last 2 statements

```
foo.on("ready", function() {
    console.log("Blah");
});

foo.Something();
```

Comment: I also worked this out the very second you posted the comment. I could have sworn that I did this earlier when preparing to post the question, but obviously not / I might have had other issues getting in the way. My code now works correctly. Thank you!